# plot constant Y for date range on Xaxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, linechart

I want to know if there is a method in any of the plotting react libraries where I can provide a start and end date for a timeseries on x axis and constant y value for that range. I dont want to generate data for each day between the start and end date because of huge amount of data.

I am expecting something similar to hlines in matplotlib